# Firebase,Swift: Retrieving only those `autoID` node's which have a specific key

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

**Question--->**

1. Is there a way to retrieve a node whose key is an  `autoID`, which **Might** contain a particular key. Like in below JSON structure i have a child node `powers` inside some `autoID`'s, *not all of them*, I want to retrieve only those nodes which have key `powers` in them not knowing what corresponding `value` might be .
2. In the below two suggested approach which one would **consume less BandWidth**?

*My JSON Tree*

```
node1   
  -node12  
    -autoId1  

        expo: "5122223333"
        users:   
            -MqrvHRBTRcPzrvAOdkklBzeFW7E2  
                firstName: "Margery"  
                lastName: "Lady" 
    -autoId2  
        powers: "Triple3"
        expo: "2123338983"
        users:   
            -LqrsadaDs12BTRcPzrvABzeFW7E2  
                firstName: "Tyrion"  
                lastName: "Imph"
  -node21  
    -autoId3  
        powers: "Triple"  
        expo: "5123333"
        users:   
            -MqrvHRBTRcPzrvAOdkklBzeFW7E2  
                firstName: "Cersie"  
                lastName: "Lady" 
    -autoId4  
        powers: "Quad"  
        expo: "2128983"
        users:   
            -LqrsadaDs12BTRcPzrvABzeFW7E2  
                firstName: "Sansa"  
                lastName: "Lady"
```

**What Have I Tried--->**

- Retrieve the entire `node12` and then checking which of the *autoId*'s have a particular `key`. for eg lets say powers: "Triple3"

  ```
  let prntRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("node1").child("node12")
  prntRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(snap) in

    if snap.exists(){

       for each in snap.value as! [String:AnyObject]{

               prntRef.child(each.0 as! String).child("powers").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(IMsnap) in

             if IMsnap.exists(){

                  //Found The correct node
                  }
              })
          }
        }else{

           //
          }
     })
  ```
- My other alternative solution is:-

  ```
  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("node1").child("node12").queryOrderedByChild("powers").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(snap) in

     if let snapDict = snap.value! as? [String : AnyObject]{

             print(snapDict.keys.first!)   //Retrieving My AutoID .Nut this gives me entire node. 

          }

          for each in snap.value as! [String:AnyObject]{

               print(each.0)   //Retrieving My AutoID 

         }
     })

  })
  ```

**Note:-** I found somewhat similar Q posted in Firebase forum, but no one seems to answer it :-https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ZDHKwxRMiKQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the value of `powers`, you only care that the key exists under the autoId node, you just need `.queryEqualToValue("")` (this is dependent on the value of the key-value pair being a string, for a number, instead of "" just use 0 [dependent on your values being greater than or equal to 0]).

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath("node1/node12")

ref.queryOrderedByChild("powers")
ref.queryEqualToValue("")
ref.observeEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snap in

    print(snap) // all the autoId nodes that have the powers key
})
```